# Is this behaviour of op-amp buffers normal?

Tags: voltage-divider, buffer

I am trying to buffer a voltage divider and I am not sure if I miss something or doing something wrong so I ask here for sanity check. I use a PC power supply and I have tested a -12V/12V channel and a -5V/5V. I have tested 3 chips: TL084, LM324, UA741.

I connect the power to a 50k trimmer pot and I test the output with a multimeter I get the expected results (following the rails correctly): -12V/12V and -5V to 5V.

When I connect the voltage divider to the non-inverting input of the mentioned op-amps configured as buffers according to their datasheets i.e. with a short from output to the inverting input, the output of the op-amps is quite different than the voltage divider. I miss around a volt on the positive rail. The tl084 specifically has the weird behaviour in the negative rail when the voltage gets a lot negative (let's after -10V) it gets positive...  So can someone give me some clue why is this case, is it normal or I am doing something wrong?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ffLKKP.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Look up "phase reversal"

Comment: Your text discusses a split-rail supply. Your schematic shows a single rail supply.

Comment: Not -12V label. That's a double negative. Just 12V.  The symbol orientation has meaning too.

Comment: Labeling it as -12V is the same as labeling 12V but flipping that supply around. It's like saying the basement is -1 floor below ground level, which means +1 floor above ground level. So it's wrong. You either say -1 floor above ground level or +1 floor below ground level.

Comment: See the tidied schematic. Since V4's + is at the top you assign +12 to the voltage source, not -12. The addition of VM1 shows where you are measuring the voltage. You could add another on the pot for clarity.

Comment: @Tom, I was writing an answer to the question (regarding the 8k resistor) you've just deleted. If you undelete it I'll post it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Besides the "phase reversal", already mentioned in the comments, look for these two limitations in the datasheets:

[image]

*source: TL081 ST datasheet*